# Doing a file_put_contents() for a base64_decoded string returns an empty image

Tags: php, base64

I am receiving from the client a base64 image and upon doing so I call a `base64_to_image` method I via:

`$barcode = base64_to_image( $barcodeBase64, ".jpg" );`

this calls the method which is:

```
function base64_to_image($base64_string, $type) {


    $data = substr($base64_string, strpos($base64_string, ',') + 1);

    if (!in_array($type, [ '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png' ])) {
        throw new \Exception('invalid image type');
    }

    $data = base64_decode($data);

    if ($data === false) {
        throw new \Exception('base64_decode failed');
    }


    $fullname = time().$type;

    if(file_put_contents($fullname, $data)){
        $result = $fullname;
    }else{
        $result =  "error";
    }

    return $result; 
}
```

It does generate an image that is ~3kb and 0w x 0h. I don't know why. The base64 that reaches the server string is this:

```
data:image/svg+xml;base64,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
```

Am I missing something/doing something wrong here?

**EDIT**
I can correctly view the base64 string if I input it in the URL, also I double-checked that it's a valid string after removing the `data:image/svg+xml;base64,` so I'm lost =/

Answer (score 0):

The SVG code (please don't save SVG pictures with `.jpg` extension, that's just looking for trouble) includes a `display: none;` attribute for some reason:

```
<svg id="barcode" width="442px" height="87px" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 442 87" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px);
display: none;">
```

If you get rid of that it displays normally. You can, e.g., remove with with JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById("barcode").style.display = "block";
```

```html
<svg id="barcode" width="442px" height="87px" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 442 87" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px); display: none;"><rect x="0" y="0" width="442" height="87" style="fill:#ffffff;"/><g transform="translate(10, 10)" style="fill:#000000;"><rect x="0" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="6" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="12" y="0" width="6" height="50"/><rect x="22" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="26" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="34" y="0" width="6" height="50"/><rect x="44" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="52" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="56" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="66" y="0" width="6" height="50"/><rect x="78" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="82" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="88" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="100" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="104" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="110" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="116" y="0" width="8" height="50"/><rect x="126" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="132" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="136" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="144" y="0" width="6" height="50"/><rect x="154" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="162" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="166" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="176" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="182" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="186" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="198" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="210" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="214" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="220" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="226" y="0" width="8" height="50"/><rect x="236" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="242" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="246" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="254" y="0" width="6" height="50"/><rect x="264" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="272" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="276" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="286" y="0" width="6" height="50"/><rect x="298" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="302" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="308" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="320" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="324" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="330" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="336" y="0" width="8" height="50"/><rect x="346" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="352" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="356" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="364" y="0" width="6" height="50"/><rect x="374" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="378" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="386" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="396" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><rect x="406" y="0" width="6" height="50"/><rect x="414" y="0" width="2" height="50"/><rect x="418" y="0" width="4" height="50"/><text style="font: 15px monospace" text-anchor="middle" x="211" y="67">1234  5678  9012  3465  7890  1234  5678  9012</text></g></svg>
```

**Edit:** I've just realised that Chrome ignores the attribute anyway so this solution probably only applies to non-webkit browsers (aka Firefox and Internet Explorer) :-?

Comment: Hi, so 2 questions: 1) why is the jpg asking for trouble? (no problem in using png really) and 2) would the display matter if what I'm trying to do is send the base64 to convert it to an image to save on the server?

Comment: 1) You'll typically open the file double-clicking on it and wrong extension will launch the wrong viewer. SVG and JPEG (and PNG) are entirely different file formats! 2) Same with web servers: if they detect file types by extension, the wrong Content-Type will be sent and standard-compliants browsers won't be able to display the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I got little code from other thread, did little change

```
$content = file_get_contents($base64);
file_put_contents("output1.jpg", $content)
```